# Hardlinks in linux command line input

Tags: linux

Hard links cannot span physical devices. Exactly this statement I read while understanding the concept of hard link in Linux. Can anyone help me to understand this ?

Comment: Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and [*Operating systems: three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Try reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290525/why-are-hard-links-only-valid-within-the-same-filesystem if you want a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

A filename, is a [*pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to an [*inode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

So if you're not on the same drive, it's impossible to link a file, because the inodes belongs to a specific disk